# Merging Dictonaries in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#

i've three Dictonaries like

```
Dictionary<int,List<string>> D1 = new Dictionary<int,List<string>>(); 
Dictionary<int,List<string>> D2= new Dictionary<int,List<string>>(); 
Dictionary<int,List<string>> D3 new Dictionary<int,List<string>>(); 


D1[1] = new List<string>{"a","b"}; 
D1[2] = new List<string>{"c","d"}; 
D1[3] = new List<string>{"e","f"}; 
D1[4] = new List<string>{"h"}; 

D2[1] = new List<string>{"a","b"}; 
D2[2] = new List<string>{"c","d"}; 
D2[3] = new List<string>{"e","f"}; 
D2[4] = new List<string>{"g"}; 
D2[5] = new List<string>{"b","h"}; 
D2[6] = new List<string>{"f","l"}; 
D2[7] = new List<string>{"z"};
```

i need to merge the two dictonary into a single dictonary

like

```
D3[1] = {"a","b","h"} 
D3[2] = {"c","d"} 
D3[3] = {"e","f","l"}
```

Merging Rule:

D1[1]={"a","b"} this list will be compared with the values in the D2

D2[1]={"a","b"}

D2[5]={"b","h"}

so the above three will be merged into

D3[1]={"a","b","h"}

is there any idea to do this using LINQ

Comment: I don't see the merge logic here. Nothing correspond between D1/D2 keys/values and D3. Please explain.

Comment: Just like the last time you asked this, you have to *explain the rules* for getting from the source data to the target data, otherwise anyone trying to help you is at best guessing what you want.

Comment: I do not understand what you are merging exactly. D1 has 4 entries, D2 has 7 entries and yet D3 has 3 entries...

Comment: @  Julien Lebosquain  ,AakashM and  Ronald Wildenberg: Edited in

Comment: Then I would expect `D3[2] = {"c","d","f","l"}` as in `D3[2] = D1[2] U D2[2] U D2[6]`. Is the algorithm mapping the space taken by D2 (length 7) mapped to D1 (length 4), so D2[5] is added to D3[1], D2[6] to D3[2] and D2[7] to D3[3] (modulo array mapping).

Oh, I guess it is searching for all lists in D2 containing values from D1?

Comment: @  Jaroslav Jandek : yes ..you are correct...  it is searching for all lists in D2 containing values from D1

Comment: Why is D2[5] being combined with D1[1] and D2[1]?

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen: its not like that, D1[1] is merged with D2[1] and D2[5] because those three is having common elements

Comment: So how about the code in my answer? I have tested it and it produces the output as you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However are you trying to merge the values, you will probably want to use one of these options:

```
D3[1] = D1[1].Union(D2[1]);
```

or

```
D3[1] = D1[1].Concat(D2[1]);
```

**Edit** - an ugly-looking method for joined merges Linq-style:

```
foreach (var kvp in D1)
{
    D3[kvp.Key] =
        (from string letter in kvp.Value
        select
            (from IEnumerable<string> list in D2.Values
            where list.Contains(letter)
            select list)
             // Union all the D2 lists containing a letter from D1.
            .Aggregate((aggregated, next) => aggregated.Union(next)))
        // Union all the D2 lists containing all the letter from D1.
        .Aggregate((aggregated, next) => aggregated.Union(next))
        // Convert the unioned letters to a List.
        .ToList();
}
```

The code keeps the lists in D2, it would be pretty easy to modify the code to remove the matched lists from D2.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (maybe needs optimisation)?

```
     var lr =
    (from gr in
        (from pair in D1.Union(D2).Union(D3)
         group pair by pair.Key)
     select new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<List<string>>>(gr.Key, gr.Select(x => x.Value))
    ).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.Aggregate((t, s) => (new List<string>(t.Union(s)))));
```