# Dictionary<enum,class> merging without duplicate?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have struggled to find the logic to con-cat or merge the two dics ..

```
enum type
{
 First,
 Second,
 Third
}

Class sample
{
 string name;
 int no;
}
public static Dictionary<type,List<sample>> GetDataDir(Dictionary<type,List<sample>> data1,Dictionary<type,List<sample>> data2)
{
   Dictionary<type,List<sample>> dataOut = new Dictionary<type,List<sample>>();
   // here one of the sample instance (data1) and key name is equal condition ,we have to update the data1 dic with key and update the sample of data2
   return dataOut ;
}
```

please help me to find the way to come out ...

Comment: Please add some examples of `data1` and `data2` and specify exactly how are you going to merge this two dictionaries.

Comment: Does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569142/linq-merge-the-dictionaries

Comment: `dataOut[key] = value;`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    internal enum sampleEnum
    {
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Dictionary<sampleEnum, sampleValue>();
            var b = new Dictionary<sampleEnum, sampleValue>();

            a.Add(sampleEnum.a, new sampleValue());
            a.Add(sampleEnum.b, new sampleValue());

            b.Add(sampleEnum.a, new sampleValue());
            b.Add(sampleEnum.b, new sampleValue());
            b.Add(sampleEnum.c, new sampleValue());
            b.Add(sampleEnum.d, new sampleValue());

            // Add missing b values into a
            foreach (var objItem in from l2 in b where !a.ContainsKey(l2.Key) select l2)
            {
                a.Add(objItem.Key, objItem.Value);
            }

            // Merge b's values into a
            foreach (var objItem in from l2 in b where a.ContainsKey(l2.Key) select l2)
            {
                a[objItem.Key] = objItem.Value;
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(true);
        }
    }

    internal class sampleValue
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Here duplicate keys only removed from dic b..my exact need is when key matches and If dic b's samplevalue instance matches with dic a's samplevalue instance ,have to update the dic a's sample value with dic b's sample value.

Comment: I wasn't 100% on how you needed the merge I will update the example in a few minutes

Comment: logic achieved for an class, i need for list of classes in value(Dictionary<sampleEnum, List<sampleValue>) ,here i have to check both a and b dic instance of sample value if matches then replace a's sample class into b's.

Comment: so you need to merge the lists as well so a[key] list will be b[key] list merged?

Comment: thanks for all answers and suggestions ,i resolved my problem by applying linq query in those dictionaries upon my requirement...